# SQL for concatenating strings/rows into one string/row? (How to use FOR XML PATH with INSERT?)

Tags: sql, sql-server, xml, string-concatenation

I am concatenating several rows/strings in an table (on Microsoft SQL Server 2010) into a string by using a method as suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/545672):

```
SELECT ',' + col FROM t1 FOR XML PATH('')
```

However, if I try to insert the resulting string as (single) row into another table like so:

```
INSERT INTO t2
SELECT ', ' + col FROM t1 FOR XML PATH('')
```

I receive this error message:

```
The FOR XML clause is not allowed in a INSERT statement.
```

`t2` currently has a single column of type `NVARCHAR(80)`. How can I overcome this problem, i.e. how can I collapse a table `t1` with many rows into a table `t2` with row that concatenates all the strings from `t1` (with commas)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Rather than xml path why not do it like this?

```
DECLARE @Cols VARCHAR(8000) 
SELECT @Cols = COALESCE(@Cols + ', ', '') + 
    ISNULL(col, 'N/A')
FROM t1
Insert into t2 values(@Cols);
```

Comment: I see this more often when concatenating string, that people use `COALESCE()` with just 2 arguments. Is there a reason to use `COALESCE()` here rather than `ISNULL()`? I've used `ISNULL()` in these cases and didn't have problems with it evaluating `@Cols + ', '` only once or anything.

Comment: +1 VG but I still can't get the `ISNULL` part to work (result is `null` instead of `N/A`). I am using a subquery that starts with `SELECT ... AS col ...` instead of `t2`. Any further ideas?

Comment: Show me the exact query.

Answer (score 2):

You need to cast it back to an `nvarchar()` before inserting. I use this method, deletes the first separator as well and as I'm doing the `, type` part, it handles entities correctly.

```
insert into t2
select stuff((
    select ', ' + col from t1
    for xml path(''), type
).value('.', 'nvarchar(80)'), 1, 2, '')
```

So you concatenate all `col` with prepending comma+space as an xml-object. Then you take the `.value()` of child with xquery-path `.` which means "take the child we are at, don't traverse anywhere". You cast it as an `nvarchar(80)` and replace a substring starting at position `1` and length `2` with an empty string `''`. So the `2` should be replaced with however long your separator is.